# SPSS : RECODE Difficulty

Tags: spss, statistics

As far  know, `IF`  is more efficient when used to execute a single, CONDITIONAL TRANSFORMATION.
For multiple `IF` statements to define the condition,  it is usually more efficient to use the `RECODE` command.

I have the following commands in SPSS :

```
IF (EDUC>12 AND GENDER='M')GROUP=1.
IF (EDUC<12 AND GENDER='M')GROUP=2.
IF (EDUC>12 AND GENDER='F')GROUP=3.
IF (EDUC<12 AND GENDER='F')GROUP=4.
EXECUTE.
```

Now i tried to RECODE the above commands as:

```
COMPUTE GROUP = 0
RECODE GROUP (EDUC>12 AND GENDER='M'=1)(EDUC<12 AND GENDER='M'=2)(EDUC>12 AND GENDER='F') (EDUC<12 AND GENDER='F').
EXECUTE.
```

But it's showing error.

How can i recode the above commands ? or is it possible to recode it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RECODE` only takes a 1 to 1 mapping, and old value to a new value, it does not accept conditional statements like you have specified. You might consider a `DO IF` block in this circumstance. (Hopefully no one has exactly 12 for education!)

```
DO IF (EDUC>12 AND GENDER='M').
  COMPUTE GROUP=1.
ELSE IF (EDUC<12 AND GENDER='M').
  COMPUTE GROUP=2.
ELSE IF (EDUC>12 AND GENDER='F').
  COMPUTE GROUP=3.
ELSE IF (EDUC<12 AND GENDER='F').
  COMPUTE GROUP=4.
END IF.
```

This evaluates the `IF` statements case by case, and so if you have 1 million records falling into the `(EDUC>12 AND GENDER='M')` and only a few falling into the other categories, for those million cases it will evaluate the first condition as true and will not evaluate the subsequent `IF` statements (which is not true of writing out the equivalent `IF` on multiple lines).